# Xcode no longer showing stack trace by thread in the debugger navigator on pause

Tags: ios, xcode

Really scratching my head at this one. Normally when I pause an app via a breakpoint, I see all of the threads in the debug navigator just below the "Network" area, with a stack trace in each thread. I'm not seeing anything.

I have "View process by thread" selected in the Debug navigator

I can see the threads in the bar above the lldb console (context menu is open)

Here is a screenshot.

[image]

Losing my mind!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It’s because you are filtering for UIAlert at the bottom of the debug navigator pane (bottom left of screen shot). Click the x in a circle to cancel the filter.